# error reading and writing files in cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am reading file from SharePoint and writitng in GCS bucket but when I run the function it gives me error "Error [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'test.xlsx'"
here is the code

```py
response = File.open_binary(ctx,location/file )
                      
blob = bucket.blob('/sharepoint/' + doc)
print('connection')
with open("test.xlsx", "wb") as local_file:
    blob.upload_from_file(local_file)
    local_file.close()
```

please help if anyone know the solution of this error

Answer (score 0):

Doing this **open("test.xlsx", "wb")** destroys the file. The file is also locked while open which causes the error message.

Change your code to open the file in **read** mode:

```
with open("test.xlsx", "rb") as local_file:
    blob.upload_from_file(local_file)
    local_file.close()
```